# How to prove the double sample trick inequality $\frac{1}{2} \Pr[|v_1-p| \geq 2 \epsilon] \leq \Pr[|v_1-v_2| \geq \epsilon]$?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

$x_i$ is i.i.d random variables with mean $p$. $v_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}$, $v_2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}{x_i}$.Then
$\frac{1}{2} \Pr[|v_1-p| \geq 2 \epsilon] \leq \Pr[|v_1-v_2| \geq \epsilon]$ is a lemma to prove VC bound in statistical learning. However, I feel hard to prove it. Any hints?

Comment: Is the second $v_1$ supposed to be $v_2$?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, no. It is $v_1-v_2$.

Comment: You have two *different* equations for $v_1$. One says $v_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}$, while the other says $v_1 = \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}{x_i}$. It makes the statement of the problem a little confusing.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland,excuse me, $v_2 = \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}{x_i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orignal problem is a lemma to prove

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1(\phi)-E[\phi(z)]|} \geq 2\epsilon]  \leq \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1(\phi)-\mu_2(\phi)|} \geq \epsilon]
\end{equation}

where $\mu_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{z_i}, \mu_2 =  \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n}{z_i}$. And also $n \geq \frac{\ln(2)}{\epsilon^2}$.

Now we directly prove the general theorem. The prove of the lemma can be adapted from this proof in a straight-forward way.

Fix $z_1,z_2,...,z_{2n}$. Consider $\phi^*$

\begin{equation}
\phi^* = \arg\sup_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1-E[\phi]|}
\end{equation}

We have relationship

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
&I[|\mu_1(\phi^*)-\mu_2(\phi^*)| \geq \epsilon|] \\
\geq & I[|\mu_1(\phi^*)-E[\phi^*]| \geq 2\epsilon] \land I[|\mu_2(\phi^*)-E[\phi^*]| \leq \epsilon]] \\
=& I[|\mu_1(\phi^*)-E[\phi^*]| \geq 2\epsilon]I[|\mu_2(\phi^*)-E[\phi^*]| \leq \epsilon]]
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Taking expectation on both sides,

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
& \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1(\phi)-E[\phi(z)]|} \geq 2\epsilon]  \Pr[|\mu_2(\phi^*)-E[\phi(z)]| \leq \epsilon] \\
\leq & \Pr[|\mu_1(\phi^*)-\mu_2(\phi^*)| \geq \epsilon] \\
\leq & \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1-\mu_2|} \geq \epsilon]
\end{array}
\end{equation}

According to Chernoff Bound and the condition that $n \geq \frac{\ln(2)}{\epsilon^2}$,

\begin{equation}
 \Pr[|\mu_2(\phi^*)-E[\phi^*(z)]| \leq \epsilon] \geq 1-2e^{-2n\epsilon^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

Now we conclude that

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1(\phi)-E[\phi(z)]|} \geq 2\epsilon]  \leq \Pr[\sup\limits_{\phi \in \Phi}{|\mu_1(\phi)-\mu_2(\phi)|} \geq \epsilon]
\end{equation}